# Create a filter in Sphinx with text/string value

Tags: php, sphinx

I have Sphinx Search installed as my search engine and I'm trying to add a few extra features to the search using `setFilter()` and `SetSelect()` which should allow me to do `WHERE/AND` clauses. But whenever I try a search, it returns no results instead of results.

Here is my sphinx.conf: http://pastebin.com/M6Kd71u0

And here's the PHP code:

```
require("sphinxapi.php");

$host = "localhost";
$port = 9312;
$index = "llgenre";
$select1 = "cartoon";
$label6 = "children";
$type = 4;
$limit = 20;
$ranker = SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25;
$mode = SPH_MATCH_ALL;

$sphinx = new SphinxClient();
$sphinx->setServer($host, $port);
$sphinx->setConnectTimeout(0);
$sphinx->setMatchMode($mode);
$sphinx->setRankingMode($ranker);
$sphinx->setSelect('*, select1="'.$select1.'" AND label6="'.$label6.'" AS mycond');
$sphinx->setFilter('mycond', array(1));

$res = $sphinx->query($type, $index);

die(var_dump($res));
```

How can I search by `type = 4`, filter by `select1` with `cartoon` and finally on `label6` with `children`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe what you're attempting to do is to filter strings as attributes.  Referring to the [Sphinx FAQ](http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/), they outline the procedure

> How do I filter, sort, or group by
>   string column without string
>   attributes?
>
> You can do all of this, except for
>   precise arbtrary-length sorting over
>   several indexes.
>
> To filter and group, you can replace
>   the string with an unique numeric ID.
>   Sometimes its possible to create a
>   lookup dictionary in the database (eg.
>   for fixed lists of cities or
>   countries), or even use an existing
>   one, replace strings with their IDs in
>   that dictionary, then filter and group
>   on that ID. If not, **you can always
>   replace the string with its checksum,
>   eg. CRC32() or (any) 64 bits taken
>   from MD5() at indexing time (no need
>   to alter the tables!), store it using
>   sql_attr_uint or sql_attr_bigint
>   respectively, and then filter or group
>   on that checksum attribute.** (Note that
>   there's a certain chance of CRC32()
>   collisions if you have millions of
>   strings but practically zero chance of
>   MD5() collisions.)

So, in my sphinx.conf, I might have the following...

```
sql_query = SELECT CRC32(string_field) AS `string_field` FROM `table`

sql_attr_uint = string_field
```

Then in PHP, I would apply a filter on the field like so...

```
$sphinx->SetFilter('string_field', array(crc32( 'filter_string' ));
```

--

Unfortunately, PHP has an annoying problem(bug?) when converting to crc32... something involving unsigned integers or something..

I use the following function to convert correctly

```
class Encode {
    public static function crc32($val){
        $checksum = crc32($val);
        if($checksum < 0) $checksum += 4294967296;
        return $checksum;
    }
}
```

--

Be careful of character case!  You may choose to convert the column to lower case while indexing eg.

```
sql_query = SELECT CRC32(LOWER(string_field)) AS `string_field` FROM `table`
```

and searching...

```
$sphinx->SetFilter('string_field', array(crc32(strtolower( 'Filter_String' )));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, although very late. So I found the same answer, there 's some time. I put your reply in acceptance because it is exactly what I struggled for several days